# How to run a docker operator task from airflow which itself runs in a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have a docker container running on my windows machine, which was build with an adapted version of the [docker-compose file provided in the official docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html).

This works fine, however I would like to move the python scripts, which are my tasks out of the mounted `plugins` folder and into their own docker containers.

To test this I have created a simple "Hello World!" example-script:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    print(f'Hello World')
    print(np.random.random((3, 3)))
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which together with the following simple docker-file

```
FROM python:3.9

ADD main.py .
RUN pip install numpy

CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

I can create my image with `docker build -t docker-test-image .`
Running this from the CLI with `docker run --name docker-test-container docker-test-image` will give me the expected output:

```
Hello World
[[0.20923763 0.25415024 0.95603957]
 [0.01320074 0.58392589 0.24175036]
 [0.06431375 0.87276564 0.9912474 ]]
```

So far so good, however if I trigger the DAG with my docker-operator it fails and I get a several

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> errors in the logs.

My DAG script looks like this:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator
from datetime import timedelta

with DAG(
    dag_id= 'docker_test_dag',
    description='Testing the docker operator',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['docker_test'],
    default_args={
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 0,
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
    }
) as dag:

    docker_test_task = DockerOperator(
        task_id='docker_test_task',
        image='docker-test-image',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        mount_tmp_dir=False,
        container_name='docker-test-container',
        command='echo "this is a test message shown from within the container',
        docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
        network_mode='bridge'
    )

    docker_test_task
```

After digging around a bit, I assumed that this is a Docker-in-Docker issue, the most likely solution was [found in this tutorial](https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/). I added `- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` to the volumes section in my airflow docker-compose file.  No the DAG still fails with the following log error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 450, in send
> timeout=timeout   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 786, in urlopen
> method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2](https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/)   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py",
> line 550, in increment
> raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py",
> line 769, in reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 710, in urlopen
> chunked=chunked,   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 398, in _make_request
> conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1327, in
> _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1036, in
> _send_output
> self.send(msg)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 976, in send
> self.connect()   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py",
> line 30, in connect
> sock.connect(self.unix_socket) urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py",
> line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
> return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py",
> line 181, in version
> return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py",
> line 46, in inner
> return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py",
> line 237, in _get
> return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 542, in get
> return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 529, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 645, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 501, in send
> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
> PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py",
> line 360, in execute
> self.cli = self._get_cli()   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py",
> line 390, in _get_cli
> return APIClient(base_url=self.docker_url, version=self.api_version, tls=tls_config)   File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py",
> line 197, in **init**
> self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py",
> line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
> f'Error while fetching server API version: {e}' docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API
> version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission
> denied'))

How is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer at last:

In the docker-compose file instead of

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

use this on a windows machine:

```
- //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Small change, big effect I guess..

Comment: Where is this line supposed to go exactly in the `docker-compose.yml` file? I'm running into the same issue but not sure where to edit the `.yml` file to get this to work.

Comment: As far as I remember this is the docker compose file for airflow which can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.1/docker-compose.yaml).

Comment: Sorry, I meant where did you put `- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` in the `.yml` file?

Comment: Ah, I missunderstood. The line is added to the `volumes` section, right after where the folders for `dags`, `logs` and `plugins` are mounted.