# Airflow DockerOperator gives file not found error / permission denied error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, dockeroperator

I have a locally created docker container (with python script) that I can run locally as follows:

> docker run --rm -v "$PWD"/output:/app_base/output eod_price:latest
> python eod_price.py ACN -b 7 -f out.csv

This app saves the output in file `/Users/me/Documents/Python/GitHub/docker-learn/docker007/output/out.csv`

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff    647 23 Jul 22:47 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff   2628 24 Jul 06:37 Readme.md
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff  10222 12 Jul 15:54 airflow-docker-compose.yaml
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  staff     96 23 Jul 22:56 app
drwxr-xr-x@  6 me  staff    192 23 Jul 22:26 dags
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 me  staff    320 23 Jul 13:39 logs
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff    646  3 Jul 09:59 myapp-docker-compose.yaml
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  staff     96 23 Jul 22:58 output
drwxr-xr-x@  2 me  staff     64 11 Jul 22:41 plugins
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff    119 23 Jul 21:26 requirements.txt
```

In airflow-docker-compose file I have added additional volumes for input and output directory

```
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./input:/opt/airflow/input
    - ./output:/opt/airflow/output
```

In the dags directory I am trying to run this in apache airflow

```
eod_price = DockerOperator(
    task_id='get_eod_price',
    image='eod_price',
    api_version='auto',
    command='python eod_price.py ACN -b 7 -f out.csv',
    container_name='eod_price-container',
    auto_remove=True,
    mounts=[
        Mount(source='/opt/airflow/output',
              target='/app_base/output',
              type='bind'),
    ],
    mount_tmp_dir=False,
    docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
    network_mode='bridge'
)
```

However, I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error

Other things I tried in DockerOperator are:

- add & remove host_tmp_dir
- remove mount_tmp_dir

I followed another similar issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940422/how-to-run-a-docker-operator-task-from-airflow-which-itself-runs-in-a-docker-con) and in airflow docker compose I added additional volume x-airflow-common:

> ```
> - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
> ```

However, that changed error to `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.

I am on Mac OS

- Any tips how to resolve this?
- What is the easiest way to debug airflow problems?
- What I do not get is that is this error due to wrong mounting of volume in DockerOperator function or some other issue. I cannot make out if airflow did not even find the container image (eod_price) or was error in execution of the image.

*Edit:*
I followed yet another solution at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499661/airflow-dockeroperator-fails-with-permission-denied-error). This solution `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` also did not work. I also tried to run it with TCP wrap solution and then I get a new error, so I reverted back.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I fixed it by:

- Added additional volume x-airflow-common
- Replace *docker_url* args with docker_url='tcp://docker-proxy:2375' for all DockerOperators