# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘cpuset’: Read-only file system when running a "service docker start" in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have a Dockerfile that extends the [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) `2.5.1` base image. What I want to do is be able to use `docker` inside my `airflow` containers (i.e. docker-in-docker) for testing and evaluation purposes.

My `docker-compose.yaml` has the following mount:

```yaml
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

My Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.1
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release nano
RUN mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
RUN echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
RUN groupadd -f docker
RUN usermod -a -G docker airflow
RUN service docker start
USER airflow
```

Basically:

- Install `docker`.
- Add the `airflow` user to the `docker` group.
- Start the `docker` service.
- Continue as `airflow`.

Unfortunately, this does not work. During `RUN service docker start`, I encounter the following error:

```
Step 11/12 : RUN service docker start
 ---> Running in 77e9b044bcea
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘cpuset’: Read-only file system
```

I have another Dockerfile for building a local `jenkins` image, which looks as follows:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release nano
RUN mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
RUN echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
RUN groupadd -f docker
RUN usermod -a -G docker jenkins
RUN service docker start
USER jenkins
```

I.e. it is exactly the same, except that I am using the jenkins user. Building *this* image works.

I have not set any extraneous permission on my `/var/run/docker.sock`:

```
$ ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jan 18 17:14 /var/run/docker.sock
```

My questions are:

1. Why does `RUN service start docker` not work when building my `airflow` image?
2. Why does the *exact same* command in my `jenkins` Dockerfile work?

I've tried most of the answers to similar questions, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499661/airflow-dockeroperator-fails-with-permission-denied-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73096783/airflow-dockeroperator-gives-file-not-found-error-permission-denied-error), but they have unfortunately not helped.

I'd rather try to avoid the `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` solution if at all possible, and it should be since my `jenkins` image can build correctly...

Comment: docker-in-docker doesn't run a docker service inside the container. It has the CLI installed and accesses the host's docker daemon through the volume mapping of `/var/run/docker.sock`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the `RUN service start docker` line.

The `docker` CLI tool needs to connect to a Docker daemon, which it normally does through the `/var/run/docker.sock` Unix socket file.  Bind-mounting the socket into the container is enough to make the host's Docker daemon accessible; you do not need to separately start Docker in the container.

There are several issues with the `RUN service ...` line specifically.  Docker has a kind of complex setup internally, and some of the things it does aren't normally allowed in a container; that's probably related to the "cannot create directory" error.  In any case, a Docker image doesn't persist running processes, so if you were able to start Docker inside the build, it wouldn't still be running when the container eventually ran.

More conceptually, a container doesn't "run services", it is a wrapper around only a single process (and its children).  Commands like `service` or `systemctl` often won't work the way you expect, and I'd generally avoid them in a Docker context.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the explanation. My specific problem was being caused by the fact that my mount was being overriden at another location, so I ended up with a `/var/run/docker.soc` (note the `.soc` instead of `.sock`) file. Fixing this fixed the issue.

Comment: That being said, do you have any idea why the `RUN service docker start` would work at all in the other image? That, I don't quite get...

Comment: No idea, but I'd also delete it there.  (It shouldn't work and it won't do anything useful.)