# Trouble Attempting to run a Docker Image from an Airflow DAG

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am trying to set up a DAG to run a Docker Image but having an issue running it.

I'm using the [official Airflow docker-compose file](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html).

My DAG file:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

from datetime import datetime

with DAG (
    "population", 
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), 
    schedule_interval='@daily', 
    catchup=False
) as dag:

    task_a = DockerOperator (
        task_id="task_a",
        image='population:1.0',
        command='python3 population.py',
        docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
        network_mode='host'
    )
```

When I visit the Airflow UI and run the DAG, I get errors saying `no such file or directory is found`.

**Errors:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 411, in execute
    self.cli = self._get_cli()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 442, in _get_cli
    base_url=self.docker_url, version=self.api_version, tls=tls_config, timeout=self.timeout
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
    f'Error while fetching server API version: {e}'
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
[2023-02-20, 19:20:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1323} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=population, task_id=task_a, execution_date=20230220T192021, start_date=20230220T192023, end_date=20230220T192023
[2023-02-20, 19:20:23 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:105} ERROR - Failed to execute job 36 for task task_a (Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')); 80)
[2023-02-20, 19:20:23 UTC] {local_task_job.py:208} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-02-20, 19:20:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2578} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

I believe it has something to do with not correctly mounting the volume in the `docker-compose.yml` file but not sure where I need to specify the volume in the file.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940422/how-to-run-a-docker-operator-task-from-airflow-which-itself-runs-in-a-docker-con) already asked but doesn't specify *where* the volume line is supposed to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer:

I ran into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70100729/17667524) that suggested adding a new service to the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  docker-proxy:
    image: bobrik/socat
    command: "TCP4-LISTEN:2375,fork,reuseaddr UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock"
    ports:
      - "2376:2375"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I also added:

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

under `x-airflow-common`

then, in the DAG file:

```
docker_url='tcp://docker-proxy:2375',
```

and it ran the DAG without issue.
Looks like there was a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/770#issuecomment-252560286) on this as well.